# Trouble Displaying data from Firebase in Next 13 App Directory using getServerSideProps

Tags: firebase, next.js, server-side-rendering

I am having trouble displaying the props.houses data in my Next 13 application with Firebase.
I'm certain firebase credentials are configured correctly, I had client side fetching of the data which worked well. I want to use getServerSideProps to display this data.

```
import { db } from "../firebase-config";
import { collection, getDocs, query, orderBy } from "firebase/firestore";
export default function Home(props) {
  return (
    <main className="p-0 m-0">
      {/* <Listings houseList={props.houses} /> */}
      {props.houses}
    </main>
  );
}
export async function getServerSideProps() {
  const housesCollectionRef = collection(db, "Houses");
  const firestoreQuery = query(
    housesCollectionRef,
    orderBy("CreatedAt", "desc")
  );
  const data = await getDocs(firestoreQuery);
  const houses = data.docs.map((doc) => ({ ...doc.data(), id: doc.id }));
  return {
    props: {
      houses,
    },
  };
}
```

I have a houses.map() function inside the Listings component, but the data is not being fetched correctly as I get an error that houseList isn't defined.

```
export default function Listings({ houseList }) {
  const [houses, setHouses] = useState(houseList);
  return (
    <>
      <div className="">
        <div className="">
          {houseList.map((house) => (
            <Link key={house.id} href={`/listings/${house.id}`}>
              <Card listing={house} />
            </Link>
          ))}
        </div>
      </div>
```

I tried narrowing down the problem.  trying to display object `{props.houses}` displays nothing. I think the error is with fetching.